# CSS Issue: Sentences do not start from the same starting point

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the following appearance of my page:

[image]

Instead, what I have right now is the following:

0023230123 - The item has blab babrf fhgdf fdgdfg fdgfdg fdgfd fdgdf fdgdf fdgvberg
and also dfsd sddexf.

In other words, I want that the item Description, if it is too long for one line, I want the second (third, forth etc) line will begin from the same point as the first line.

My code is as follows:

[image]

item.id is the numeric identifier of the item:  0023230123

item.Description is the text: The item has blab babrf fhgdf fdgdfg fdgfdg fdgfd fdgdf fdgdf fdgvberg and also dfsd sddexf.

Any suggustion on how to achieve this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to float the spans so the browser lays them next to each other.

See here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M9689/)

Example HTML:

```
<span class="itemize">Item ID 1</span>
<span class="separator"> - </span>
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...</span>

<span class="itemize">Item ID 2</span>
<span class="separator"> - </span>
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...</span>
```

Example CSS:

```
span {
    float: left;
}

span.itemize {
    clear: both;
    width: 70px;
}
span.separator {
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

span.text {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That sounds an awful lot like it's tabular data, in which case that kind of layout would come pretty much for free.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>0213515351</td>
            <td>This item has bla bla bla and also sdljfhbsdf lsjhdbfsjlhdbfsjhdfbsjhdbf</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr286/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>0023230123</div>
    <div class='cell'>Description is the text: he item has blab babrf fhgdf fdgdfg fdgfdg fdgfd fdgdf fdgdf fdgvberg and also dfsd sddexf.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display:table;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
.cell:first-child:after {
    content:'-';
    margin:0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case the number is of a fixed width and you'd like to use a HTML list, it can also be done this way:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li id="0023230123">The item has blab babrf fhgdf fdgdfg fdgfdg fdgfd fdgdf fdgdf fdgvberg and also dfsd sddexf.</li>
    <li id="0023230123">The item has blab babrf fhgdf fdgdfg fdgfdg fdgfd fdgdf fdgdf fdgvberg and also dfsd sddexf.</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    padding-left: 90px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Consolas, monospace;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
li:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: attr(id) ' - ';
    display: block;
    margin-left: -90px;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7VQc5/3/)</kbd>.